# where do mac apps put their files?

Tags: macos, resources, clang

I've got a Mac app that I'm building with clang and make.  It needs a bunch of resource files that my makefile puts in foo.app/Contents/Resources but when I open the app from Finder, it fails to find those files.  Let's say the file I'm trying to read is foo.app/Contents/Resources/myfile; a call like ifstream(myfile) fails (at least, the stream reports is_open == false).

I put in a call to filesystem::current_path() and it reports that it's in the directory where the app is located.  And sure enough, if I prepend foo.app/Contents/Resources/ to myfile, ifstream("foo.app/Contents/Resources/myfile") finds it and opens it just fine.

But that's not how it's supposed to work.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

If it helps, my Makefile:

```
CC = clang++

CFLAGS = -g -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-c++11-extensions
# CFLAGS = -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-c++11-extensions -fsanitize=address
# CFLAGS = -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-c++11-extensions

TARGET = nfl

SRCS = nfl.cpp
OTHER_SRCS = actions.cpp info.cpp io.cpp model.cpp

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
OTHER_OBJS = $(OTHER_SRCS:.cpp=.o)

WX_CONFIG = ./wx-config

NFL_VERSION = 0.1

CXX_EXTRA = -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 `$(WX_CONFIG) --cxxflags` -DWX_PRECOMP
LINK_EXTRA = -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 `$(WX_CONFIG) --libs` -lm

$(TARGET): $(OBJS) $(OTHER_OBJS)
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(OTHER_OBJS) $(LINK_EXTRA)

convert: convert.o io.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o convert convert.o io.o

%.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CXX_EXTRA) -c $< 

app:
    mkdir -p nfl.app/Contents
    mkdir -p nfl.app/Contents/MacOS
    mkdir -p nfl.app/Contents/Resources
    sed -e "s/VERSION/$(NFL_VERSION)/" \
    Info.plist.in >nfl.app/Contents/Info.plist
    echo -n "APPL????" >nfl.app/Contents/PkgInfo
    cp nfl nfl.app/Contents/MacOS/nfl
    cp -f wxmac.icns nfl.app/Contents/Resources/wxmac.icns
    cp -f full.csv nfl.app/Contents/Resources
    cp -f detailed_model nfl.app/Contents/Resources
    cp -f elapsed_model nfl.app/Contents/Resources

app:  nfl Info.plist.in wxmac.icns

deps: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CXX_EXTRA) -MM $(SRCS) $(OTHER_SRCS)

clean:  
    rm -f $(TARGET) *.o

convert.o: convert.cpp data.h
model.o: model.cpp data.h
io.o: io.cpp data.h

nfl.o: nfl.cpp nfl.h data.h
actions.o: actions.cpp nfl.h data.h
info.o: info.cpp nfl.h data.h
```

and my Info.plist.in file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
<plist version="0.9">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>mattginsberg.com</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>nfl</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>wxmac.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>nfl</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>VERSION</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>VERSION</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright (c) 2020 Matthew Ginsberg LLC.</string>
    <key>CSResourcesFileMapped</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I built wxWidgets with --enable-debug --disable-shared.

Comment: I assume this is C++? Could you add a [mcve] please?

Comment: The current working directory doesn't really have much to do with the location of the app or its files. I think you want [pathForResource:ofType:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1410989-pathforresource) or something similar (see "Locating Resources in a Bundle" [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-resourcePath)).

Comment: It is C++.  I'm not sure about a minimal reproducible example; it *looks* just like the wxWidgets image example (which has a disk file that it uses), but it doesn't work!  In case it helps, here are my Makefile and Info.plist.in -- if I had to guess, I would say that the problem is somewhere in there.